# Create xml file in binary format in C#

Tags: c#, xml, binaryfiles

I want to create a xml file which has xml declaration, root node and child nodes.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tag1>
  <SubTag>
    <Id>
    </Id>
    <Name>IdentityManagement</Name>
    <Time>4/11/2017 6:26:15 PM</Time>
    <Message>Message1</Message>
  </SubTag>
  <SubTag>
    <Id>
    </Id>
    <Name>MainWindow</Name>
    <Time>4/11/2017 6:26:20 PM</Time>
    <Message>Message2</Message>
  </SubTag>
</Tag1>
```

But I need to write this xml in binary format, so no one can read it.
On calling of one function, one can add another SubTag.
So there can be n number of .

Comment: *But I need to write this xml in binary format* What do you mean? Do you have a binary format in mind? There are infinite possible binary formats.

Comment: If no one should be able to read it, encrypt it. You can also simply encode it to base64 encoding.

Comment: If " so no one can read it. " means if someone open file in Notepad can't read it, you can use  `XmlWriter.WriteBinHex`  or `XmlWriter.WriteBase64`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert it into a form that is not trivially readable by a human, encode it to base64:

`Convert.ToBase64String(textAsBytes);`

If it should not be readable by anyone under any circumstances, encrypt it.

I am not sure what you mean when you say 'binary' though, all text is already binary when stored in a file, it is just encoded using an encoding scheme like ASCII or UTF8.